# MVC Form :- Dropdown List:- Posting form getting Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, dropdown, sitecore-mvc

While using the Dropdown list in MVC form and Submitting it , getting Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
Form Submit successfully if  remove the drop-down field.

Controller.cs

```
  [RedirectAuthenticated]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {

            var model = this.UserProfileService.GetEmptyProfileRegistrationInfo();
            return this.View(model);
        }

 public virtual RegistrationInfo GetEmptyProfileRegistrationInfo()
        {
            return new RegistrationInfo
            {
                InterestTypes = this.profileSettingsService.GetInterests()
            };
        }

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateModel]
        [RedirectAuthenticated]
        [ValidateRenderingId]
        public ActionResult Register(RegistrationInfo registrationInfo)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(registrationInfo.Interest) && !this.UserProfileService.GetInterests().Contains(registrationInfo.Interest))
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(registrationInfo.Interest), DictionaryPhraseRepository.Current.Get("/Accounts/Edit Profile/Interest Not Found", "Please select an interest from the list."));
                registrationInfo.InterestTypes = this.UserProfileService.GetInterests();
            }
            if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return this.View(registrationInfo);
            }


            if (this.AccountRepository.Exists(registrationInfo.Email))
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(registrationInfo.Email), UserAlreadyExistsError);

                return this.View(registrationInfo);
            }


            try
            {
                this.AccountRepository.RegisterUser(registrationInfo, this.UserProfileService.GetUserDefaultProfileId());

                var link = this.GetRedirectUrlService.GetRedirectUrl(AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated);
                return this.Redirect(link);
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"Can't create user with {registrationInfo.Email}", ex, this);
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(registrationInfo.Email), ex.Message);

                return this.View(registrationInfo);
            }
        }
```

Model

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.Accounts.Models
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using Sitecore.Feature.Accounts.Attributes;
    using Sitecore.Foundation.Dictionary.Repositories;

    public class RegistrationInfo
    {
        [Display(Name = nameof(InterestsCaption), ResourceType = typeof(RegistrationInfo))]
        public string Interest { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> InterestTypes { get; set; }


        public static string InterestsCaption => DictionaryPhraseRepository.Current.Get("/Accounts/Edit Profile/Interests", "Interests");
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out the issue , I have initialize and passed the model with DD "list values" on Load of page into Register() ActionResult .

```
@using Sitecore.Foundation.Dictionary.Extensions
@using Sitecore.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Extensions
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration
@model Sitecore.Feature.Accounts.Models.RegistrationInfo

@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, FormMethod.Post, new{ @class = "form-signin"}))
{
    @Html.AddUniqueFormId()



    <div class="form-group @Html.ValidationErrorFor(x => x.Interest, "has-error")">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Interest, new
                                        {
                                            @class = "control-label"
                                        })

        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Interest, new SelectList(Model.InterestTypes), "", new
            {
                @class = "form-control",
                id = "InterestTypes"
            })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Interest, "", new
                                                        {
                                                            @class = "help-block"
                                                        }, "p")
    </div>


    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="@Html.Sitecore().Dictionary("/Accounts/Register/Register", "Register")" />
}
```

[image]

---

Try With below code but still Error

```
**[HttpPost]
        [ValidateModel]
        [RedirectAuthenticated]
        [ValidateRenderingId]
        public ActionResult Register(RegistrationInfo registrationInfo)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(registrationInfo.Interest) )
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(registrationInfo.Interest), DictionaryPhraseRepository.Current.Get("/Accounts/Edit Profile/Interest Not Found", "Please select an interest from the list."));
                var model = this.UserProfileService.GetEmptyProfileRegistrationInfo();
                return this.View(model);
            }
            if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return this.View(registrationInfo);
            }


            if (this.AccountRepository.Exists(registrationInfo.Email))
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(registrationInfo.Email), UserAlreadyExistsError);

                return this.View(registrationInfo);
            }


            try
            {
                this.AccountRepository.RegisterUser(registrationInfo, this.UserProfileService.GetUserDefaultProfileId());

                var link = this.GetRedirectUrlService.GetRedirectUrl(AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated);
                return this.Redirect(link);
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"Can't create user with {registrationInfo.Email}", ex, this);
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(registrationInfo.Email), ex.Message);

                return this.View(registrationInfo);
            }
        }**
```

Comment: You have not shown your POST method!

Comment: Sorry, Added post method

Comment: Your not setting the value of `InterestTypes` in all the possible cases where you return the view, so its `null` (hence the error)

Comment: But On "HttpGet" I am able to see the DropDown with value(added Image).. While posting I am getting error.

Comment: Yes, because you do NOT set the value of `InterestTypes` when you return the view in the POST method (as you did in the GET method) - when you return the view, the `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Interest, new SelectList(Model.InterestTypes) ...)` code is execute again but this time `Model.InterestTypes` is `null`

Comment: Thanks, Let me try now

Comment: Tried with updated code (at last) , but no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174756/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-shailesh).

Comment: Problem with "ValidateModel" attribute , after removing its working.

Comment: namespace Sitecore.Feature.Accounts.Attributes
{

  public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      var viewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData;

      if (!viewData.ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                               {
                                 ViewData = viewData,
                                 TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
                               };
      }
    }
  }
}